# Postgres: How to view contents of a table?

Tags: postgresql

Here is what I have?

```
contacts=# \l
                                 List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |  Collate   |   Ctype    |   Access privileges
-----------+----------+----------+------------+------------+-----------------------
 contacts  | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 |
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 |
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |            |            | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |            |            | postgres=CTc/postgres
(4 rows)

contacts=# \d
             List of relations
 Schema |     Name      | Type  |  Owner
--------+---------------+-------+----------
 public | SequelizeMeta | table | postgres
(1 row)

contacts=# select * from SequelizeMeta;
ERROR:  relation "sequelizemeta" does not exist
LINE 1: select * from SequelizeMeta;
                      ^
contacts=# contacts=# select * from public.SequelizeMeta;
ERROR:  relation "public.sequelizemeta" does not exist
LINE 1: select * from public.SequelizeMeta;
                      ^
```

How do I read the contents of `SequelizeMeta`?

Thanks

Comment: `select * from "SequelizeMeta";`  (or: don't use mixed case identifiers)

Comment: Thanks a lot `wildplasser`. That was the issue

Comment: @wildplasser why do I need  " "?

Comment: Because identifiers are considered to be case-insignificant in SQL. You can force them to be case-significant by quoting them with double quotes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Based on `wildplasser` command, this is what I had to do. Thank you `wildplasser`

```
contacts=# select * from "SequelizeMeta";
 name
------
(0 rows)
```